# Show that ||A||_2 = √(ρ(AA*)) where ρ(AA*) is the spectral radius of the AA* matrix.

Tags: matrices

Show that ||A||2 =  √(ρ(AA*))  where ρ(AA*) is the spectral radius of the AA* matrix.

I know ||A||_2 = max ||Ax||_2/||x||_2 x=!0
then I square ||A||_2 obtaining:
(||Ax||_2)^2/(||x||_2)^2 x=!0

= max x * AA * x/x * x

= λ max AA*

Then
(||A||_2)^2 = ρ(AA*)

= ||A||_2 = √ρ(AA*)

But I don't know why

- max x * AA * x/x * x = λ max AA* = ρ(AA*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T=A^*A$, and we write $|.|$ for Euclidean norm. The matrix $T$ is a "normal matrix" (i.e. $TT^* = T^*T$). Normal matrix has specially nice properties; one of the important property is that any normal matrix can be diagonalized by unitary matrix, that is, we can express $T$ by

$$ T = PDP^* $$

where $D=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ is a diagonal matrix and $P$ is a unitary matrix. Now, we have

$$ \lVert A \rVert^2 = \max_{|x|=1} \{ x^*A^*Ax \} 
= \max_{|x|=1} \{ x^* T x \} 
= \max_{|x|=1} \{ (P^*x)^* D (P^*x) \} $$

Since $P$ is unitary matrix, $|P^*x| = 1$ for $|x|=1$ and we can define $z = P^*x$. The maximization becomes:

$$ \max_{|z|=1} \{ z^* D z \} 
= \max_{|z|=1} \{ \lambda_1 z_1^2+...+\lambda_n z_n^2  \} $$

The values of all $\lambda_j$ are nonnegative. (To see this, suppose $(A^*A)v = -c v$ with $c \geq 0$. Then $ v^*(A^*A)v = |Av|^2 \geq 0$  but $v^*(A^*A)v = (-c)|v|^2 \leq 0$ which leads to contradiction.)

Therefore, the maximization is attained when the vector $z$ has a direction with the largest eigenvalue (say, $\lambda_1$), and we have $ \lVert A \rVert^2 = \lambda_1 = \sigma(A^*A)$.

Finally, we use the fact that $ \lVert A^* \rVert = \lVert A \rVert $ and hence
$$ \sigma((A^*)^*(A^*)) = \sigma(AA^*) = \sigma(A^*A) $$.